# SSL Certification for telegram api webhook

Tags: apache, ssl, webhooks, telegram, self-signed

I've set self-signed SSL certificate on my local virtual host, setup redirect in router from MyGlobalIP:8443 to MyLocalIP:443
It works fine for browser, but if I check my hook with telegram api method getWebhookInfo I get a error message

"SSL error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"

I cant find any solution how to fix this. I cant even find kind of problem, bad certificate or bad apache settings or something else.

```
php 7.1
apache 2.4
mac os x sierra
```

Comment: If you use a self-signed certificate, you have to upload it when you call `setWebhook`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes, I doing it

Comment: I have same situation here, I have heard that Telegram Webhook is not working well with IP and only domain name is supported!
If you have solved it please let us know.